# Dynamic loaded DLL calling back to the one that loaded it

Tags: c#, events, dll, interface

I am loading DLL's dynamically from my main application. Normally the main application uses functions from the DLL, but I am not sure if it is possible for the DLL to call in a method main application, and what is the best practice for this purpose.

I was wondering if this can be done by use of events or if an interface can be used.

What do you suggest?

Comment: Do you mean P/Invoke or just regular .NET assemblies?

Comment: a .NET assembly I made myself. The main application calls a method in the DLL. From that method I need to be able to e.g. throw a messagebox on the UI, hence I need to call a method in the main application that takes a string to be shown.